# Order of a differential equation .

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Order of a differential equation is the order of the highest order derivative (also known as differential coefficient) present in the equation. In my local book it is written that Order of a differential equation is always defined but degree may not defined always. But by confusion is what will be order of a differential equation of the form $$\frac{df}{dx}+\frac{d^{2}f}{dx^{2}}+\frac{d^{3}f}{dx^{3}}\cdot\cdot\cdot=0.$$ According to me its order is not define. Please suggest me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

We generally study differential equations of the form $$F[t, u(t), u'(t), u''(t), \ldots, u^{(n)} (t)] = 0$$ which is of the $n$-th order. We should understand what is the difference between the degree and order of a differential equation.

The **order** is the highest numbered derivative in the equation, while the **degree** is the highest power to which that derivative is raised.

So, you are correct in saying that the equation of the form $ y'+ y'' + y''' +\cdots$ has undefined order, although **such differential equations do not exist**. Hope it helps.

Comment: i am also thinking like this....